# How can I solve my error problem when compiling the program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a car register with different function, in different files, `lib.c`, `lib.h` and `main.c`.  However when I try to compile the program it shows this error with my car "unknown type name ‘Car’
34 | void addCar(Car* car)":

In my 'lib.c' file, this is my progress so far:

```
#include "lib.h"

void printMeny() {

 //meny
printf("Meny\n");
printf("1. Lägg till ett fordon\n");
printf("2. Ta bort ett fordon\n");
printf("3. Sortera efter bilmärka\n");
printf("4. Information om ett fordon\n");
printf("5. Skriv ut hela registret\n");
printf("0. Avsluta programmet\n"); 
}

int getNumber()  {
char buffer[10] = {0}; 
int number = 0;
fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),stdin);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &number);

  return number;
}

void getString(char* buf, size_t len) {

if(fgets(buf,len,stdin)) {
    char* p;
    if((p = strchr(buf, '\n')) != NULL)
    {
        *p = '\0';
    }    
 }
 }
 void addCar(Car* car) {

printf("Namn:\n");
getString(car->owner.name, sizeof(car->owner.name));
          
printf("Ålder:\n");          
car->owner.age = getNumber();

printf("Märke:\n");          
getString(car->car_brand, sizeof(car->car_brand));
          
printf("Modell:\n");          
getString(car->car_model, sizeof(car->car_model));
          
printf("Registreringsnummer:\n");          
getString(car->plate_num, sizeof(car->plate_num));        
}
```

Then in my `lib.h`:

```
 //#pragma once
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

  #define CAR_MAX 10




   typedef struct {
   char name[40];
   int age;

   } Person;

   typedef struct {
   Person owner;
   char car_brand[20];
   char car_model[20];
   char plate_num[20];
   } Car;


      void printMeny();
     int getNumber();
    void addCar(Car* car);
    void getString(char* buffer, size_t len);
```

And finally in main.c;

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "lib.h"
int main() {
int val = 0;  
Car cars[CAR_MAX] = {0};
int numberOfCars = 0;

printMeny();
val = getNumber();



switch(val) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1: 
    addCar(&cars[numberOfCars]);
        numberOfCars++;
```

Comment: How should  `main.c` know what `Car` is without including the related header?

Comment: I have included #inlcude "lib.h" i main.c as well. Still same problem

Comment: [Not reproducible](https://godbolt.org/z/WhWW8ojjG).

Comment: As mentioned by @n.m., we can't reproduce the error you are facing. Would you please explain how the *.h and *c files are organized (are they in the same folder?) and maybe post the command you use to compile?

Comment: Okay, so when i run the command  gcc -o prog main.c lib.c lib.h, the error says error: unknown type name 'Car'  in  34 void Car* car in lib.c and it'S the pointer that's the problem, Car*. All of files are in the same folder

Comment: I am not getting this error (or any error) with the code you have shown. Please verify that the code you are compiling is the code you are showing us and not some slightly different version.

Comment: It's exactly the same, I have checked line by line multible times in all the files.